# I have an array of strings. I want to print those that start with the word New.

Tags: python

I have an array of strings. I want to print those that start with the word New.

```
input_arr = [
    "New: Hello",
    "How are",
    "you",
    "New: I am",
    "fine"
]

def merge_messages(input_arr):
      #don't know that to do here
  return input_arr

print(merge_messages(input_arr))

#Expected Output
[
"New: Hello How are you",
"New: I am fine"
]
```

Comment: A) Indent your code with four spaces for proper formatting. B) *Try* and solve your problem, don't just panic and post on Stack Overflow. If you need mentoring or coaching try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).

Comment: Man show us what you have tried so far

Comment: I have tried nothing coz i am beginner in python and ain't abe to solve this code

Comment: read this article http://thepythonguru.com/python-strings/ specifically you want to look at slicing strings, using `in`, and comparing strings. Everything you need to solve this is in that article

Comment: Can anyone please provide me the answer

Comment: If we just give you code @YashKaushik, that really won't help you learn. When given homework, the goal is to become a good problem solver. Here's some hints though. **(1)** You'll need a `for`-loop to iterate over each message. **(2)** You'll need a variable to store each message. **(3)** Think about the logic of your program. While iterating, if the current string starts with `'New: '`, you need to store the current message and reset the message holding variable. Otherwise, add the current string to the current message. If you sit down and think through this, I know you can solve it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
input_arr = [
    "New: Hello",
    "How are",
    "you",
    "New: I am",
    "fine"
]

def merge_messages(input_arr):
  delimiter = "New"
  return [delimiter+x for x in " ".join(input_arr).split(delimiter) if x]

print(merge_messages(input_arr))
```

However, I would highly recommend you take the advice given to you in the comments and read up on Python Strings. You can also view the Python string documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)